# How to sort items in node orm find

Tags: node.js, orm, node-orm2

I want to get sorted items using find method in node orm. I know there is and 'order' param in find(), It will give me sorted items from 'a-z'. What will I do if I want to get items from 'z-a' order That means how the 'GROUP BY DESC' can be used in node-orm?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for group by

UserModel.find({id: id_value}).groupBy({column1, column2}).order('-name').

In the ORM library you can find the below function which will guide you more.

```
export interface SelectQuery {
select(fields: string): SelectQuery;
calculateFoundRows: SelectQuery;
as(alias: string): SelectQuery;
fun(fun: string, column: string, alias: string): SelectQuery;
from(table: string, from_id: string, to_id: string): SelectQuery;
from(table: string, from_id: string, to_table: string, to_id: string): SelectQuery;
where(...args: any[]): SelectQuery;
whereExists(table: string, table_link: string, link: string, conditions: { [column: string]: any }): SelectQuery;
groupBy(...columns: string[]): SelectQuery;
offset(offset: number): SelectQuery;
limit(limit: number): SelectQuery;
order(column: string, direction: string): SelectQuery;
build(): string;
}
```